# how to open a file instead of typing in variable sockets python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

i have this piece of code in python where i display hello world when i run my web socket

```
f = open("index.html")
        http_response = """\
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

    Hello, World!
    """
```

now my output in the browser displays as

```
Hello, World!
```

but i want the html script in the variable `f` to be displayed 
how could i go about doing that
i tried concatenating but it didn't seem to work my code for the concatenation was this

```
    http_response = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK """ + f.read()
```

Comment: The question is not related to the [tag:websocket] tag, but rather [tag:http].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has to be one empty row between the header block and the body. You did not leave that empty line.

One way would be to just concatenate normal strings:

```
http_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n" + f.read()
```

Another is to use `format` or `%`:

```
http_response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n%s" % f.read()
```

Yet another is to use the new f-strings:

```
http_response = f"""\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{f.read()}\
"""
```

There are more (e.g. joining an array of lines, etc...) but whichever method you use you need to make sure that HTTP protocol is obeyed, which mandates that that empty line be there.

Also note that if `f.read()` does not produce text, you will need headers to describe what you're transmitting, and possibly take steps to encode it correctly. You'd also be a "nice netizen" if you return the correct `Content-Length` if you know it. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) for a nice overview of HTTP, and the linked RFCs if you want to know more.